# Annotating a QuerySet with joined tables in Django

Tags: django, join, annotate

*How can I annotate a Django QuerySet with data from a custom join expression, without using raw SQL?*

I'd like to translate the following query for the Django ORM, without having to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500066) :

```
SELECT a.*, b.name as b_name
FROM a
JOIN b ON ST_Within(ST_Centroid(a.geom), b.geom)
```

As far as I could tell, the best candidate for doing something like this it the `annotate(...)` function, but the documentation didn't have anything on how to add a joined table to the annotated QuerySet.

My other idea was to use something similar to `ManyToManyField` (maybe subclass it) that can use custom `ON ...` expressions for its joined model.

Any other idea?